# Is "discussion instantanée" really the best translation of "chat"?

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

I set my Facebook to display in French and it changed "Chat" to "Discussion instantanée." Is that really what online chat is called in French? Is there not a more felicitous term than that?

In English I suppose we call it *instant messaging,* but it's *always* abbreviated to *IM*. Is it called *DI* in French? And can that be used as a verb, like "Il m'a DIé" ? (I have no idea how you form the tenses of an "improvised" verb in French.)

Comment: Ben voyons, toi qui est un habitué pourtant ! **Causette**. C'st le mot recommandé par la [**Commission générale de terminologie et de néologie**](http://www.education.gouv.fr/bo/1999/14/encart.htm). Mais c'est vrai que pas beaucoup de gens ne l'utilisent en dehors de FL. En France du moins, peut-être que c'est différent au Québec.

Comment: Et aussi salon de clavardage, Voir http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/8838/abbreviation-of-instant-messaging

Comment: @Laure Ah ouai quand même...

Comment: Most french use the word "chat" though from my experience  :')

Comment: Il y a aussi la version francisée "tchat" qui a l'avantage d'éviter la confusion avec l'animal.

Comment: Your guess on tenses of "improvised" verb is actually correct. For example, we would say "je t'ai poké" (I poked you). However I can't think of an abbreviation of French words that we conjugate. Also, as said above, tchatter / chatter / tchatcher (for older people who confuse the existing French word with the English one) are commonly used

Comment: À quoi ressemble une discussion qui n'est pas instantanée?

Comment: Depending on which side of the Atlantic you’re on, “piquer/faire [une] jasette/causette” are used for the pre-internet, [engaging in a] face-to-face informal conversation, meaning of *chat* in English.

Comment: @mouviciel Une discussion peut sans doute être différée. Cela dit, je vous accorderait le mot correspondance pour désigner ce genre d'échanges.

Comment: @mouviciel : le genre épistolaire se prête parfaitement aux discussions différés

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Le meilleur par élimination : *Messagerie instantanée*.**

**Messagerie**, car c'est bien ce type d'échange.

Instantané, car c'est **très rapide** (plus que de l'email). On pourrait dire messagerie rapide (mais non utilisé, et la messagerie *express* fait référence aux coursiers).

En pratique, les outils font défiler les échanges (souvent limités à une ou deux lignes).

Les échanges continus entre 2 personnes par SMS sont une forme de chat. Pour mémoire, les SMS sont une messagerie (le M).

Comme la poste ne délivre pas le courrier de manière instantanée, le terme messagerie instantanée reflète nécessairement **le caractère en ligne** (alors que l'email est moins réactif et qu'on a ajouté le e ou électronique). **C'est donc la forme la plus courte qu'on puisse trouver pour restituer l'idée.**

Evidemment, *chat* (prononcer *tchat, tchatter* ...) est aussi utilisé en France très couramment.

à noter que si on se met à tchatter à plusieurs, cela finit par être un forum en ligne ... => communication instantanée.

Le terme *communication instantanée* serait plus précis justement mais il est moins utilisé, et il ne restitue pas le caractère électronique.

**Pour mémoire, on parle d'un terme et d'une technique issus d'un protocole internet qui a presque 30 ans** ([IRC, bien résumé sur wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Relay_Chat)), traduit en *communication instantanée*.

Ceux qui sont moins bons (mais pas faux):

- dialogue instantané est très **imprécis**: forcément on dialogue (mais pourquoi pas face à face), idem pour *discussion*;
- dans le même esprit on pourrait dire échange instantané (mais on peut échanger des transferts d'argent) ;
- communication peut se référer au téléphone (ou à la voix, à la vidéo), idem pour dialogue;
- **tout ce qui ne reflète pas le caractère numérique est imprécis** (dialogue, échange). Les exemples fournis le sont dans un contexte **déjà** numérique (réseaux sociaux, ...);
- les termes officiels causette et autres ont beau être jolis, il ne sont pas utilisés (et par ailleurs une causette est surtout une petite discussion);
- l'expression *en temps réel* est pour un public averti, et pas toujours bien comprise du grand public (qu'est-ce que le *temps irréel* ?);

Finalement, si on veut être précis en utilisant les autres termes, il faut restituer **les 4 composantes**:

- échange;
- caractère écrit / frappé;
- numérique;
- très rapide.

**Ce qui donne sous une forme *longuette* :
*discussion/échange/dialogue/communication écrite en ligne immédiat/instantané***

**Quand on parle d'échange vidéo:**

videochat = échange/communication vidéo (instantané/e) (forcément numérique, et généralement, mais pas toujours instantané).

Comment: C'est bien *l'instantanéité*, due à l'irruption de l'électronique dans le *courrier dématérialisé*, qui définit ***les messages*** de toutes sortes que les correspondants inscrivent et découvrent en même temps sur leur écran qui définit ce type d'échange. --  ***Un message est un ensemble de signes. Il implique donc un codage par l'émetteur, et un décodage par le récepteur (d'où la nécessité d'un code commun)*** Cf. Wikipédia

Answer (score 5):

According to the [French Academy](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/questions-de-langue#12_strong-em-anglicismes-et-autres-emprunts-em-strong), you can find french equivalents here: [France Terme](http://franceterme.culture.fr/)"

Searching for *chat* gives the following result:

> **dialogue en ligne** (Journal officiel du 05/04/2006)
>
> *Forme abrégée :* **dialogue**, n.m.
>   *Domaine :* TÉLÉCOMMUNICATIONS - INFORMATIQUE / Internet
>   *Définition :* Conversation entre plusieurs personnes connectées en même temps à un réseau, qui échangent des messages s'affichant en temps réel sur
>   leur écran.
>   *Équivalent étranger :* **chat (en)**
>
> *Attention :* Cette publication annule et remplace celle du terme « causette » au Journal officiel du 16 mars 1999.

Answer (score 3):

*Le lexique.* La France a finalement opté pour « [dialogue en ligne](http://www.culture.fr/franceterme/result?francetermeSearchTerme=dialogue%20en%20ligne&francetermeSearchDomaine=0&francetermeSearchSubmit=rechercher&action=search) », après *[causette](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/19067/is-discussion-instantan%C3%A9e-really-the-best-translation-of-chat#comment36329_19067)*, afin de rendre « *chat* », qu'on définit comme la « Conversation entre plusieurs personnes connectées en même temps à un réseau, qui échangent des messages s'affichant en temps réel sur leur écran. ». Au GDT on a [*clavardage*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8392463), *bavardage-clavier*, *cyberbavardage* et *bavardage en ligne* à l'entrée « chat » où on note aussi que « Le clavardage peut réunir des internautes provenant du monde entier, qui voient leurs commentaires affichés simultanément sur l'écran d'ordinateur de tous les participants. » ; donc ça peut couvrir le bon vieux [*salon de clavardage*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=2075097) (chatroom). Quant à l'« *instant messaging* », on a la *messagerie instantannée* ([Franceterme](http://www.culture.fr/franceterme/result?francetermeSearchTerme=instant%20messaging&francetermeSearchDomaine=0&francetermeSearchSubmit=rechercher&action=search), [GDT](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8366749) : « Service de messagerie en temps réel, offrant la possibilité aux utilisateurs de consulter la liste des correspondants avec lesquels ils sont simultanément en ligne, pour communiquer immédiatement avec eux. » ; acronyme *MI*).

---

*L'usage.* On semble avoir pris l'idée de l'activité du *chat* (discussion, dialogue) qu'on a apposée à la caractéristique instantanée de la messagerie, pour donner *discussion instantanée*. C'est pas mal. Par ailleurs, même si certains écrivent « [MP](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/19152)/MI-moi », il est difficile de concevoir les voir le prononcer comme on le fait en anglais (épeler les lettre de l'acronyme), et je préfère personnellement des verbes expressifs qui parlent de ce qu'on fait (la communication) plutôt que de l'objet qui nous permet de le faire. En général on parle de *recevoir/envoyer* un message, [texter](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8349275) ou de *dire*, quelque chose à quelqu'un par l'entremise d'un message, d'un texto ; on peut aussi parler d'*échanger* etc. Je ne vois pas davantage d'utilité à utiliser l'acronyme du concept que le concept lui-même de *messagerie instantanée* (*faire* de la) pour désigner l'activité de manière usuelle, et le lexique propre à une fonction du logiciel d'une société lui appartient. On verra à l'usage.

Answer (score 2):

If we really want to translate "Chat" in French, then yes "Discussion instantanée" is used.

But (there's always a but), more and more people (particularly young people) use "Message privé".

So in Facebook we say "MP Moi" which means "DM me".

Answer (score 1):

Being French, I would say the best way to translate "Chat" in French would indeed be "Discussion instantanée".

Now, let's look at the verb "to chat" in French:

- [Reverso](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-french/chat) says *"bavarder", "causer"* (there is even an *Internet* definition, *"chatter"*, which I, sometimes, personally use.
- [Word Reference](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-french/chat) says *"bavarder", "discuter" "chatter", "tchatter"   ,(in Québec Canada) "clavarder"*

As you can see, there are "two" general senses: "to casually talk to someone" and "to talk to someone on Internet".

Now, if we look at "chat" as a verb (in English), we have from [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/chat):

> - To talk in a friendly and informal way
> - To exchange messages online in real time with one or more simultaneous users of a computer network

... and as a noun:

> - An informal conversation:
> - The online exchange of messages in real time with one or more simultaneous users of a computer network

We can conclude that the definitions for both the noun and the verb are quite similar in English. What would it give in French (what follows is a direct translation from the Oxford dict. definitions)?

> - "Une conversation informelle" (ie: "entre amis")
> - "Un échange de messages sur Internet **en temps réel** avec un ou plusieurs utilisateurs"

Looking at the second definition, the most appropriate definition for "a chat" in English would thus be "une discussion instantanée". Now, as far as I heard and learned, we do not "DIé" in French (although that would be really cool) but rather "chatté", "tchatté", "mp" (as mentioned by Chris - MP comes from "message privé", and instead of saying "envoyez-moi un message privé", you could say "MP-moi").

Going away from the facts, I think "Discussion instantanée" is appropriate for Facebook and other professional services whereas "Tchat" or "Chat" (not to be confused with "cat" in French) is mostly used between you and your friends.

Don't forget that Canadian French and French French are not completely identical :D

Answer (score 0):

*[La réponse Guillaume](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/20070/848)* est insurpassable, car elle contient et le sens, et le contexte contemporain.

Pour s'amuser on pourrait inventer :

> Conversation de clavier

qui remplace les conversations du café du commerce d'antan.

Ce genre de conversation est un jeu d'échange de mots entre personnes, du domaine du jeu électronique qui accueille qui veut bien y jouer lorsque le *chat* miaule en public... avec possibles boulets et *trolls*

Les *conversations de salon* seront tenues sur des *chats* privés, or anonymat.